# Is having an Embeddable with an Embeddable with a ManyToOne reference not supported in an ElementCollection?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to define an object model as follows:

A contains a list of X, each X contains a Y, and each Y refers to a B.  I've set this up having A and B as `Entity`, and X and Y are both `Embeddable`.  A contains an `@ElementCollection` of type List of X.  The code for these classes is below.

When asking Hibernate (3.6.10) to generate the SQL for this model using `SchemaExport`, I'd expect three tables: A, B, and a collection table for the reference from A to B, containing A.id, B.id, and an order column to keep the list order.  Instead, Hibernate gives me the following:

```
create table CollectionOfB (A_ID bigint not null, embeddableAList_ORDER integer not null, primary key (A_ID, embeddableAList_ORDER))
create table EntityA (id bigint not null, primary key (id))
create table EntityB (id bigint not null, primary key (id))
alter table CollectionOfB add constraint FKFEABC9AD9AECF0BB foreign key (A_ID) references EntityA
```

Note that the collection table has no column for B.id, nor is there a foreign key contraint as there should be.  It seems to me that my desired model should be supported.  Does it not work for a good reason (and if so, what is that reason?), or is this a bug/missing feature in either Hibernate or JPA?

---

As an experiment, I collapsed my `Embeddable` relationship so it only has one level (remove Y entirely, put the reference to B inside of X).  With that change, the schema is generated as I expect, so the basic idea of having an `ElementCollection` where the `Embeddable` has a `ManyToOne` works:

```
create table CollectionOfB (A_ID bigint not null, B_ID bigint, embeddableAList_ORDER integer not null, primary key (A_ID, embeddableAList_ORDER))
create table EntityA (id bigint not null, primary key (id))
create table EntityB (id bigint not null, primary key (id))
alter table CollectionOfB add constraint FKFEABC9AD9AED651B foreign key (B_ID) references EntityB
alter table CollectionOfB add constraint FKFEABC9AD9AECF0BB foreign key (A_ID) references EntityA
```

Further, if I make a different `Entity` C, and define it as having an `Embeddable` X (***not*** an `ElementCollection` of X) it correctly has a reference to B.  So the idea of having two levels of `Embeddable` where the lower level has a `ManyToOne` ***also*** works.

---

```
@Embeddable
public class EmbeddedX {
    // Comment out to "collapse" X and Y
    @Embedded
    EmbeddedY embeddedY;

    // Comment in to "collapse" X and Y
    //    @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID")
    //    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    //    EntityB entityB;
}


@Embeddable
public class EmbeddedY {
    @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    EntityB entityB;
}

@Entity
public class EntityA {
    @Id
    Long id;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "CollectionOfB", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID"))
    @Column(name = "Bs")
    @OrderColumn
    List<EmbeddedA> embeddableAList;
}

@Entity
public class EntityB {
    @Id
    Long id;
}

public void testSchema() throws Exception {
    Configuration config = new Configuration().addAnnotatedClass(EntityA.class).addAnnotatedClass(EntityB.class);
    config.setProperty(Environment.DIALECT, HSQLDialect.class.getName());

    new SchemaExport(config).create(true, false);
}
```

Comment: Note, I decided to open an issue on Hibernate's JIRA: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-8034

Comment: Now it's 2016 and Hibernate-5.1 and this issue is still present.